# Is MongoDB overkill in a local environment?

Tags: mongodb, local, database-replication

I'm building a system with one (windows 10) PC operating as a central data store and three other (Windows 10) PCs collecting data and sending it to the central store, about 20 times per second each. If the data store goes down then the data collectors need to store data until it comes back up and put it back together again.

My first thought was to use MongoDB (which I've never used before.) I'd run the data store as the primary instance with each collector having a secondary instance of it's own so one would step up to act a the primary if one went down.

I've almost talked myself out of the idea now; it seems wasteful for each collector to have a full copy of the dataset it will never query. Is there some other tool I've not heard of that I should be using?

Comment: You don't need a full copy of the DB to stage updates. If the main db is down, you can accumulate pending updates wherever you want. Even in a text/json file, for simplicity.

Comment: I'm thinking that's the way to go - I'm just going to use a standard db and I'll keep a text log of outstanding readings. Must resist the urge to use new toys!